# Reset schema for all Realms in Realm Cloud

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Is there any way I can completely nuke everything from my Realm Cloud, including existing schema definitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to delete the Realms from the Realm Object Server.

Here's information I collected on a [Realm Forums Post](https://forums.realm.io/t/delete-realm-database-from-realm-cloud/2018/6)

Here's a link to the [official docs](https://docs.realm.io/sync/v/3.x/self-hosted/customize/working-with-realms-on-the-server/deleting-realms#deleting-a-realm-with-a-http-delete-call).

**This is super important though**. The docs I am linking are for Docs 3.0. Self-hosting appears to be going away so the 3.16 Docs no longer include this information.

There are two steps

```
Remove server files
Remove all local files
```

These both have to be done or else Realm will try to re-sync itself and your data will never go away.

The first function deletes a Realm Cloud instance and if successful, deletes the local realm files.

```
//
//MARK: - delete database
//
func handleDeleteEverything() {
    let realm = RealmService //Singleton that returns my realm cloud
    try! realm.write {
        realm.deleteAll()
    }

    guard let currentUser = SyncUser.current else {return}
    let adminToken = currentUser.refreshToken!

    let urlString = "https://your_realm.cloud.realm.io" //from RealmStudio upper right corner
    let endPoint = "\(urlString)/realms/files/realm_to_delete"
    let url = URL(string: endPoint)
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    request.httpMethod = "DELETE"
    request.addValue(adminToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if let err = error {
            print("err = \(err.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        print("Realm has been deleted")
        self.deleteLocalRealmFiles() //remove local files
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

and then the function to remove the local files. This function is a bit different than what appears on the Realm Forums post with the addition of this function in Realm 4.2

```
try Realm.deleteFiles(for: config)
```

and the function that calls it

```
func deleteLocalRealmFiles() {

    do {
        let config = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration
        let isSuccess = try Realm.deleteFiles(for: config)
        if isSuccess == true {
            print("local files were located and deleted")
        } else {
            print("no local files were deleted, files were not found")
        }

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: You gotta start billing me soon, Jay. Thanks for your patience and quality answers to all my noob issues.

Comment: @OscarApeland  Lol. I hope it helps - it was a LOT of effort to pull that solution out of Realm at the time as the documentation was incorrect to start with as well as being VAGUE VAGUE VAGUE. If it does help, please be sure to accept it. Let me know if you get stuck.

Comment: Glad it's not just me struggling to get useful information from those docs. Having seconds thoughts about choosing them pretty often. I got around to trying your solution now -- it seems that this is about equal to deleting one Realm from Realm Studio + deleting the app on the installed devices. Is this any different than doing that, and is there any way I can remove absolutely everything in my cloud instance?

Comment: @OscarApeland This will completely delete a single Realm from Realm Studio and then the local files associated with the app; essentially it's a clean slate for that Realm. In other words if I have a realm at *my_realm_url.us1.cloud.realm.io/Test_Realm_1* and then another realm at *my_realm_url.us1.cloud.realm.io/Test_Realm_2*, the code in the answer will enable you to delete either *Test_Realm_1* or *Test_Realm_2*. Keep in mind that there are a number of hidden files that are stored within the url path (your cloud) which you probably don't want to remove as they contain admin account info etc.

Comment: My reason for asking this question was to resolve an issue where Query Based Sync would fail because of a schema conflict, and I can't create a new Realm Cloud because of some weird account issues I'm trying to get help with trough support. I don't know if it was your answer or me deleting all my realms in studio, but now that issue is resolved and QBS works as expected again. Accepting!

Comment: @OscarApeland Glad it helped or at least lead to a fix! Realm is so frustrating sometimes. You may be aware of it but Sync Based Queries appear to be depreciated so you may want to start working toward Full Sync. From Realm:  *Query-based Sync is not recommended. For applications using Realm Sync, we recommend [Full Sync](https://docs.realm.io/sync/using-synced-realms/choosing-your-sync-type#full-sync). Learn more about our plans for the future of Realm Sync [here](https://www.mongodb.com/realm).*

Comment: Yess, just went down that rabbit hole. As far as I understand it's not getting deprecated, just kinda shoved under the rug until later as they merge Realm and Mongo -- https://forum.realm.io/t/the-future-of-query-based-sync/3329/4. I'm dependent on QBS until my project eventually takes off and I can afford to migrate off of Realm so I'm hoping it lasts a little longer.

Comment: @OscarApeland Where would you migrate to? We've been looking for a while since Realm doesn't offer a complete multi-user feature set (Record locking, fine-grained user permissions with full sync etc).

Comment: I think I'll learn from trusting at third party this time and build my own solution. I'm already using a Vapor instance on Heroku for auth and ads, so I'd put my Realm data in a postgres database, create a REST api and use CoreData for persistence on the device. I'm developing a social network app that has two-dimensional storage of private items and a social feed, so using only Realm for data is a stretch already. It has caused much pain, so when I get time creating my own solution would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you can check this link.

https://forum.realm.io/t/is-it-possible-to-reset-the-default-realm-without-creating-a-new-instance/1466

This one solve my realm database issue and can reset all schemas

I hope it works well!

Comment: Link only answers are not super helpful as if the links break, it would invalidate the answer and there should generally be some context explaining why it's an answer. In this case, the linked post is about deleting a default realm sync'd file from the Admin GUI, not in the app. The user ended up just deleting everything via Realm Studio which is really not a good solution *I ended up... mark and scroll through everything in Realm Studio.* [Writing a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)