# 'Cannot sort on key path, property does not exist' - RealmSwift

Tags: swift, xcode, class, properties, realm

So I am getting this fatal error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Cannot sort on key path 'title': property 'Item.title' does not exist.'

I have a Class Category which contains a list of my Class Item, and the two have a Linking Objects relationship. I am using Realm, and I get the error upon clicking a Category cell in my tableview, which is supposed to bring me to a tableview of all the Items in the selectedCategory.  Here is the function (the two variables are at the beginning of my file, I put them here so you can see):

```
var toDoItems : Results<Item>?

var selectedCategory : Category? {
    didSet {
        loadItems()
    }
}


func loadItems() {

    toDoItems = selectedCategory?.items.sorted(byKeyPath: "title", ascending: true)
    
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Just to be clear, the selectedCategory gets set in my CategoryViewController through a tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow property, which is how it obtains its value in my ToDoListViewController, where the loadItems() function is.  And here are my classes of Category and Item, (in their own files of course):

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Category: Object {
    dynamic var name: String = ""
    let items = List<Item>()
}

import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Item: Object {
    dynamic var title: String = ""
    dynamic var done: Bool = false
    dynamic var dateCreated: Double = 0.0
    var parentCategory = LinkingObjects(fromType: Category.self, property: "items")
}
```

Why am I getting the error that the Item.title property does not exist? It clearly does.  I have erased and rewritten the variable, restarted Xcode, etc, and the error is still there. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Realm object is not constructed correctly. You either need to mark the individual properties as @objc

```
class Item: Object {
    @objc dynamic var title: String = ""
```

or mark the whole object as @objmembers

```
@objcMembers class Item: Object {
    dynamic var title: String = ""
```

I prerfer to specify each property as it gives more more control as some I don't always want all vars managed.

Comment: thank you, I tried that, and then I got this error: Thread 1: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=io.realm Code=10 "Migration is required due to the following errors:
- Property 'Category.name' has been added.
- Property 'Item.title' has been added.
- Property 'Item.done' has been added.
- Property 'Item.dateCreated' has been added." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Migration is required due to the following errors:
- Property 'Category.name' has been added.
- Property 'Item.title' has been added.
- Property 'Item.done' has been

Comment: Any idea how to fix that error or what it means? The app wasn't even able to start before the error arose

Comment: @derek Sure, it means that you changed the schema of your Realm objects and you have to add a [Migration](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#migrations) block to handle it. If you are in development, it's sometimes easier to to delete all of your Realm data and start fresh. Note that Migrations are handled differentlly depending on how you use realm, local, vs sync'd and then the new BETA MongoDB Realm is also different that those.

Comment: I have almost no data in my Realm Studio, and even If i do, I don't think any of it would conflict with new formatting like described in the link you attached, although if deleting the data is a good option, how do I do that? (sorry im very new to Realm).  Also, I pasted the big block of code from that link into my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, and I have the same error as before.  Am i implementing it wrong somehow? the only change Im making to the code is adding the @objc to each property, im not changing the model itself like in the example from the link you sent.  thanks

Comment: @derek You may have but no way to tell without seeing the actual code. There are a number of questions here on SO about migration blocks so between the Documentation I linked above and a little bit of searching here, you will find a lot of good and varied examples. If you just want to blow out all your data, you can either manually delete the files or use one of the new functions that does it for you. See my answer to [Deleting Realm Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59600641/reset-schema-for-all-realms-in-realm-cloud/59600766#59600766). Be sure to quit Realm Studio before deleting.

Comment: ok thanks, i will do some  more research and come back with a solution if i find one

Comment: @derek If this answer helped with *this question* be sure to accept it so it can help others. Migration is a separate question so feel free to post a question about that if you get stuck. [How To Accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

To answer the part below about why the app is still crashing, all I had to do was go to my simulator, and delete the app on the simulator, then restart it.  Fixed!